# Solution for Linux "permission denied"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permission-denied

I am pretty new to the Ubuntu environment and I have a question regarding the solution to "permission denied" error.

When I am trying to run the following command that executes a shell script and writes the result into a txt file, I get the permission denied error.

```
./test_image.sh > testCase.txt
```

I know that I can just sudo run the command, but I am hoping to do this command through a Java program and was wondering if there would be a way to give permission to any user that is trying to run this command.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Read a good Linux programming book about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) facilities (at least [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and if possible a newer book). Take a few days to read it (a bug is a huge cybersecurity risk). You'll need to code in C something using [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See of course [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, AFAIK setuid do not have effect on shell scripts

Comment: @RomeoNinov: yes, that is why I mentionned coding something in C

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have permission deny error? Maybe you need to give your script rights to execute (eg. chmod +x test_image.sh) or give the user rights to write/change testCase.txt in a given directory. I am afraid you need to learn a bit about standard permissions or even ACLs, Selinux policy, setuid, sticky bits, etc.

Comment: changed the chmod to 777 and it seemed to work. Thank you for your feedback